# I have one website that seems to be cached indefinitely on my Mac

Tags: cache, browsers, mac

I have a strange problem that I can't seem to find an answer to.  I developed a website for a client on my dev server.  I uploaded it to their live server when it was ready.  This was 2-3 months ago.  Every time I go to the website, it is stuck in the version I uploaded.  New users were added, new content was added and I do not see this info on my Mac.  I've checked in Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera, cleared all the caches, closed and shut off my computer and re-opened everything and the website is still the old version.

If I check my phone or on another computer, the new information is visible and current.  I've never had this experience.

Mac is a mid 2012 running Sierra.

Comment: Try to add a new file with same name but different content on both your dev and live sites. Then open the live site file from your Mac and from your phone. This way you can understand if your Mac actually fetches the dev site content using the live site domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a rogue cache header. Less likely is a misbehaving service worker.

It might be helpful to check the HTTP cache headers for the resources that seem stuck in the cache. Also, make sure your computer is actually fetching from the right remote server - if you ever modified your hosts file to point their domain to your dev server on your local computer, it might be that that's still active and preventing your mac from reaching the actual live site.

Comment: OMG... that was it.  I had my hosts file pointed to the old site and totally forgot I had done that.  I rarely use the hosts files feature.  Thank you so much!!!!